# How to receive Serial Data and display it periodically with java.util.timer

Tags: timer, serial-port, arduino, rxtx

I am receiving data from an arduino mega which transmits data with a delay of 500 ms. I wish to update this data on a COSM server on a periodic basis by updating a feed while receiving the data using java.util.timer. Somehow the received data is not the one that gets updated on the feed. 
Here is the output i receive on the console

```
Content-Length: 341
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eeml xmlns="http://www.eeml.org/xsd/005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-     instance" version="5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eeml.org/xsd/005   http://www.eeml.org/xsd/005/005.xsd"><environment><data id="1044">
    <tag>ecu low speed</tag>
    <value >20.0</value>
</data></environment></eeml>
```

The code for receiving the data from the serial port is :

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) 
{
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) 
    {
        try
        {
            val=input.read();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!